# Tempstar 2 stage furnace restarting every 7 minutes - not going into high

Tags: hvac, furnace, central-heating

I have a tempstar 9MPT model based furnace. Also sold under a number of other brands - comfort air, etc. It is a two stage heating with a PSC motor high efficiency furnace.  After about 7 minutes of running, instead of cycling to high fan speed and BTU output, it restarts going through the pre-blower cycle before re-engaging the blower.

Any idea where to start troubleshooting this?

Comment: Is it throwing any error codes? Can you post the precise model # of the furnace, for that matter?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Full model: t9mpt075f14c1

Comment: Not aware of any way to see error codes on this model.

Comment: Is *SW1- 3* in the on position? – [Sequence Of Operation & Diagnostics *9mpt - ICP *9MPT050F12 Installation Instruction](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1199190/Icp-9mpt050f12.html?page=46#manual) Page 47 has the codes.

Comment: Possible overheat due to restriction. [Tempstar (ICP) furnace short cycle (runs 10 -15 minutes) then repeats](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/181563/tempstar-icp-furnace-short-cycle-runs-10-15-minutes-then-repeats) - pull the filter out and see how it runs.

Comment: I have run it without the filter with the same results. This isn't at my primary residence, so won't be able to check switch position or do other troubleshooting until I return in a little over a week.  I have read on this site about potential issues with the water drain backing up so will look into that as well when I return. I am getting condensate draining, but can rule out the backup issue.

Comment: Finally got back to the site for the weekend. The flashing light is 3 flashes. "Low pressure switch open when should be closed"

Answer (score 1):

I blew out (by mouth) the rubber line coming back from the low pressure vacuum switch back to furnace near the drain. It initially had some resistance but then cleared. Everything worked fine after that.